When I duplicate the shape in edit mode, it projects all faces onto the other face. How do i turn this off? I wan't it to look like the other one

When I duplicate the shape in edit mode, it projects all faces onto the other face. How do i turn this off? I wan't it to look like the other one.

Turn off the Snap option???????


I want it to snap :)

My snap settings were on "face project" instead of "face", changing that fixed the problem for me.
